# Quotient algebra of tensor algebra, waiting with the quotients?

Tags: tensor-products, clifford-algebras

I was just wondering if we in a quotient algebra of a tensor algebra can "wait" with the quotients until we have computed the expression in the tensor algebra? This would make it simpler for my intuition if we when doing nested expressions can pretend we live in tensor algebra land and then in the end search through all the terms and see if they can be reduced with the quotient algebra rules. Can we even multiply a quotient algebra element with a normal vanilla tensor algebra element?

Comment: This is implicit in the definition of a quotient algebra (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quotient_associative_algebra)): it is not a quotient algebra unless the quotient respects the ring operations.

Comment: But the tensor multiplication is not a ring operation? (Basically I am worried I end up "outside" the quotient space if I multiply it with the "wrong tensor" or do the "wrong operation", but maybe this is unfounded, maybe it is less of a subspace and more of a forceful projection, but I know I had issues that when reordering the tensor factors extra terms popped up in the qoutient space but not in the tensor space, something called braiding map I believe, but I would like to not have the extra factors until the very end, so to speak)

Comment: Like if you want to swap places between to neighbors in the tensor an annoying scalar popped out in Clifford algebra, I wanted to know if I could ignore them (I guess set them to zero?) until the end. Or at least know what I am allowed to do in the tensor algebra without caring about the qoutient.

Comment: Or do I have to, as I suspect, keep track of all those annoying scalars. I.e. can't pretend the noncommutativity isn't there.

Comment: If I can't pretend the noncommutativity isn't there, do I need to prepare my normal "commutative tensor product"-ed terms to be in some normal form before tensor multiplying them with the qoutiented tensor which has noncommutative tensor products in it ? Or do I need to keep track of which tensor product is commutative and which one is noncommutative, some kind of hybrid thing ? Do they get promoted/infected with noncommutativity once they have swapped with a noncommutative ditto?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135563/discussion-between-qman-and-emil).